# Apex code to show records for whole week

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, soql

I want to display the record of whole week according to the day I selected.

Example: if i selected 15-08-2018 which is Wednesday, so i want the record from Monday to Sunday (13-08-2018 to 19-08-2018).

To get the weekly record of today, I had used `THIS_WEEK` literal but I want to get weekly record from any date entered by user.

Please provide any suggestion either by apex or SOQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [toStartOfWeek](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm) method of `Date` class. Returns the start of the week for the `Date` that called the method, depending on the context user's locale. For example, the start of a week is Sunday in the United States locale, and Monday in European locales.

So you can get two dates: start of the week and end of the week (add 6 days to start of the week). Next step is to query records between calculated two dates

```
Date myDate = Date.today();
Date weekStart = myDate.toStartOfWeek();
Date weekEnd = weekStart.addDays(6);

List<Account> weekAccounts = [
    select Id
    from Account
    where CreatedDate <= :weekEnd and CreatedDate >= :weekStart 
    ];
```

Comment: Thank you Oleksandr Berehovskiy for your help , It's working for me.